# Function return value when fail to allocate space

Tags: c++, pointers

```
int main()
{

 cout<<"Enter n";

 cin >> n;

 int * a = new int[n];

 a = foo(n);

 free(a);

 return -1;

}

int * foo(int n)
{
 int * a = new int [n];

 if(!a) // what should I return here if allocation of a fails 

 {}

 free(a);


}
```

In the code above I am trying to catch the return value of an function from main, the return type of the function is a pointer . However I am allocating memory dynamically . So , what should I return if my memory allocation fails ... any special symbol like NULL .

P.S - Its a very basic question and could not formalize my question to any succinct form   for to search over Google.

Edit: Thanks all of you guys . I have solved my problem .

Comment: Please write you full code. You function return nothing in both cases. Why do you need to use new two times? What do you whant to do in the very end?

Comment: Careful about mixing 'new' & free().  The 'delete' keyword should be used instead--or in this example 'delete [] a' instead of 'free(a)'.

Comment: You can't use `free` for memory allocated with `new`! You have to use `delete`, in your case since you're allocating arrays `delete []`.

Comment: Though unrelated to the question, `main` should return `EXIT_SUCCESS` from `<cstdlib>` (or `0`) when it succeeds.

Comment: I think the code needs to be modified , I need to call free from the main , not from the subroutine . Also , there is no necessary to allocate extra memory in the main .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a custom to return NULL in case of allocation failure from functions which allocate their own memory and return pointer to it. See for example [`strdup()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup). Note that operator `new` throws `std::bad_alloc` if it fails to allocate memory, so you may need to catch this if you want to return NULL or alternatively, you can let `std::bad_alloc` propagate out of the function.

Note however, that it is not always wise to return such pointers since it raises the issues of ownership and increases the likelihood of memory leaks.

You may find that sticking to the [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) idiom makes your code easier to reason about and less error prone. One consequence of RAII idiom is that allocation and deallocation are done by the same code unit.

In your particular situation you allocate the array in `main()` so you may pass the pointer to it to `foo()` and deallocate memory also in `main()`.

Also, if you use `new` to allocate, you should use a proper version of `delete` to deallocate (here `delete[]` since you allocated an array). You use `free()` to deallocate memory allocated with `malloc()` and friends.

Comment: You would use `delete []` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

`operator new` throws exception (except `nothrow operator new`), so, you can catch this exception and return `null pointer`, or rethrow, or throw other exception.

Answer (score 1):

The `new`operator throws a `bad_alloc` exception if allocation fails. So you can catch this exception and handle the error.

For exemple:

```
#include <new> // std::bad_alloc

int* foo(int n)
{
   int* a(new int[n]);

   return a; // I guess you want to return the address stored in a
}

int main()
{
   try
   {
      int* a(foo(n));
   }
   catch(std::bad_alloc& ba)
   {
      // Handle here the error (e.g: std::cerr << "Allocation failed:" << ba.what() << std::endl;)
   }

   return 0;
}
```

**EDIT1:** If you use C++11 features, forget `NULL` or `0` and use `nullptr` instead!

Answer (score 0):

If your return value is a pointer then NULL is the most logical value in the case of an error. You could also look at raising an exception, but for now returning NULL should suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The new operator would throw a bad_alloc exception in such a case and probably you should catch it and handle it according to your requirements (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/new/bad_alloc/)

Answer (score 0):

It can return any value. The thing is that then you have to treat it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!a) // what should I return here if allocation of a fails 

 { return NULL;}
```

this will imply allocation failed i.e. by returning a NULL pointer.